Micronaut Kafka Listener committing offsets even if ErrorStrategy set to RETRY_ON_ERROR on application restart
We have a Micronaut Kafka Batch Listener with the below properties:
@Singleton
@KafkaListener(
    offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST,
    errorStrategy = ErrorStrategy(
        retryCount = Int.MAX_VALUE,
        handleAllExceptions = true,
        retryDelay = "1s",
        value = ErrorStrategyValue.RETRY_ON_ERROR,
    ),
    batch = true,
)

Committing offset is configured as enable.auto.commit=true. So, our understanding is if there is an error during processing, the offset will not get committed until that issue is resolved. That's what we want so that there won't be any drop in events.. When there is a processing error of some kind(say application throwing any RuntimeException due to certain validation failure), it is keep on retrying which is what is expected. But, once we are restarting the app, the processing continues smoothly which means that the offset which triggered the exception is committed and we are getting a fresh set of offsets. Is that what is happening here? Or how it is getting resolved post application restart? Can you please help on this..
